# how many the waves(threads) are scheduled and executed on the GPU using OpenCL?

Tags: android, opencl

I'm developing android app using OpenCL with Adreno GPU. I read the 'Snapdragon OpenCL General Programming and optimization'. but I can't see any information about  size of wave(threads) or warp on Adreno devices.

On desktop GPU AMD have 64 threads wavefront size, and Nvidia GPU have 32. This information is very important for choosing best workgroup size, and making code optimization.

I wonder how many the waves are scheduled and executed on the GPU.

Can someone provide such information.

Comment: @buttifulbuttefly because I have to optimize my app. to coalesed meory access and to avoid local memory conflict, I have to know how many threads are exactly sheduled and execute on each Compute unit in Adreno GPU.

Comment: @buttifulbuttefly in that documentation page number 12, "It is crucial to understand how the waves(threads) are scheduled and exectuted on the GPU" was written. When i want to use the GPU resource effectively, I have to know how many waves(threads) executed in Compute Unit

Comment: @Mai Longdong, "But the OpenCL spec has no concept of wavefront, therefore any program exploiting something such concept is by definition non-portable. " Partially true. OpenCL code is typically target optimized. Knowing the wave size is quite helpful in many optimization cases. However, most of the chip vendors try to hide that information. You can still measure it by writing a microbenchmark. By the way, from CL2.0, the subgroup concept is designed to expose the wave size information.  :)

Comment: @Mai Longdong, please keep it in mind that, people all agreed so far that OpenCL is not performance portable. That being said, your code will be platform specific (targeting at multiple platforms? well, you will have more work to do. good luck with that). I was just debating on your statement that "wave is not recommended for optimization due to portability issue". The reason people really bother to use OpenCL is performance, not portability. Otherwise, you miss the point of using CL. And in real use cases, "wave" is already heavily used to push the performance to the limit, even on mobile.

Comment: @Mai Longdong By the way, in CL2.0, subgroup is an extension. However, in CL 2.1, subgroup will be standard. Satisfied? :)

Comment: @Mai Longdong When CL first launched, people were exited about the "portability". But as time went by, people started realizing that CL portability is a joke. You can never count on a code to run equally well on different GPUs, not to mention GPU vs CPU, desktop vs mobile, DSPs, and even FPGAs. Any serious developer should avoid the intent of using OpenCL to achieve portability. It is just unrealistic by its nature. If the goal is just "can run" on a platform, CL may be OK (not always. too many factors can make it break). In reality, I've never seen that is the goal of a product-quality code.

Comment: @RobertWang I got the answer from a researcher at Qualcomm. Thanks :)